# Proper way to describe saving canvas to server?

Tags: buttons, web-app, save, html5

## Problem

I have an app where the user draws to an HTML5 canvas, and then is presented an option to save it to the server. Currently a button that says "Save" is shown, which instructs the server to create a permanent link to the canvas, and then the user is redirected to that permanent link. However, I don't think "Save" conveys exactly what the button will do, and might cause confusion with a "Download" button next to it which allows the user to save the canvas as an image to their computer.

## Possibilities

I could call the button "Share", but I'm not sure sharing is exactly what is happening. I've also thought about "Permalink", but I'm not sure users know exactly what that would be. Perhaps "Upload" as opposed to "Download", but I have an option where users can upload an image to the canvas, so that would be confusing as well.

## Question

So what should the button say? Or am I overthinking it and is "Save" a perfectly good way to describe what I'm doing?

Comment: You functionality to me sounds a lot like [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), the user hits save a it creates/redirects to a permalink. I think save would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'upload' function sounds more like an 'import' - the object in hand is the canvas and the user is bringing something into the canvas from elsewhere.

Making that change would free up the 'upload' term for 'uploading' the canvas to the server.

Comment: 'Save' also works fine in my opinion ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to auto-direct the user to the permalink? There could be a better way to just provide the link to the image and possibly a copy to clipboard functionality. The button can be named as "Get Image URL", and the other button can be called "Download Image". It depends on the context of the app, but if you think "Get Image URL" is a bit technical for your audience then you can keep it as "Save Image". The important thing is to not re-direct them without their consent, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the save is ok, then after the redirect to the canvas link, there should be a download button there. My school has this page where you fill in the courses you want to register then click on ''Save Course Registeration'' and it takes you to the preview page which has a ''Print'' button.